# Не работает mysql ssl replication, почему?

Tags: mysql, linux

Приветствую коллеги. Решил организовать SSL коннект между мастером и слейвом. И вот борюсь уже пол дня. Итак имеем:

Master - 4.0.5-gentoo, mysql 5.6.26.

```
have_openssl   YES                                  
have_ssl       YES                                  
ssl_ca         /etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/ca-cert.pem     
ssl_cert       /etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/server-cert.pem 
ssl_key        /etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/server-key.pem
```

Slave - Ununtu 12.04 mysql 5.6.27

```
Master_SSL_Allowed: No
 Master_SSL_CA_File: /etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/ca-cert.pem
 Master_SSL_Cert: /etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/client-cert.pem
 Master_SSL_Key: /etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/client-key.pem
```

Сертификаты создавал на генту. Сейчас репликация работает и всё ок. Но вот когда я делаю

```
CHANGE MASTER TO MASTER_SSL=1
```

Получаю в логах слейва

```
SSL error: Unable to get certificate from '/etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/client-cert.pem'
[ERROR] Slave I/O: error connecting to master 'replica@1.2.3.4:3306' - retry-time: 60  retries: 1, Error_code: 2026


ls -al
total 20
drwxr-xr-x 2 mysql mysql 4096 Oct 30 00:06 .
drwxr-xr-x 5 root  root  4096 Nov  1 17:22 ..
-rwxr--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1229 Oct 30 13:51 ca-cert.pem
-rwxr--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1123 Oct 30 13:53 client-cert.pem
-rwxr--r-- 1 mysql mysql 1708 Oct 30 13:52 client-key.pem
```

Делал всё по статье с хабра HowTo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем разобрался я с проблемой сам.
1. Сертификаты должны быть в старом формате pkcs#1 (это для убунты 12.04)
2. Разрешения на сертификаты и папку где они лежат должны быть у пользователя от которого работает mysql в моем случае был (mysql). Даже если ключи лежат в `/etc/mysq/ssl` все равно нужно давать пользователю права. Проверял так - `sudo -u mysql mysql -h 1.2.3.4 --ssl-ca=/etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/ca-cert.pem --ssl-cert=/etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/client-cert.pem --ssl-key=/etc/mysql/ssl-mysql/client-key.pem -u replica -p.` 
Ответ на свою вопрос я нашел тут [ask ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/194074/enabling-ssl-in-mysql)